# Which version of solr does sunspot_solr gem use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I installed solr 4.2.1 recently... And in my rails program, i use the sunspot_solr and sunspot_rails gem... since sunspot_solr gem is a pre-packed Solr distribution, i was wondering if the program will sue the Solr 4 thati installed or will it use the version that comes with the gem? and is there a way that i can find the version of solr used by the gem?
Help would be much appreciated.. Thanks for your time in reading this question.

```
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~>2.0.0'
gem 'sunspot_solr', '~>2.0.0'
```

These are the versions that i have used in my gemfile...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer...its in the git hub page of sunspot... localhost:8982/solr gives the information abt the version of solr used by the gem and its solr 3.5 :/ .... now should find a way to use solr 4 for my program...

Comment: it's 4.2 in the current release

Answer (score 0):

For Solr 4, check out:
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Working-with-Solr-4
and
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Upgrading-sunspot_solr-Solr-Instance

I am exploring this and might patch sunspot to work with Solr 4, follow me on http://github.com/hammady

Comment: hi hammady, any news regarding updating it to solr 4?

Comment: I found that Solr4 joins won't solve my problem, so I didn't use it. The above guides are enough.